# How can a linear equilibrium temperature distribution be obtained for an ideal gas in a long tube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

In Zemansky & Dittman: Heat and Thermodynamics problem 5.8 (3rd edition, page 135) is the following

> $\bf{5.8}$ The temperature of an ideal gas in a tube of very small, constant cross-sectional area varies linearly from one end ($x = 0$) to the other end ($x = L$) according to the equation
>   $$T=T_0+ x\frac{T_L-T_o}{L} \tag{1}\label{1}. $$
>
> If the volume of the tube is $V$ and the pressure $P$ is uniform throughout the tube, show that the equation of state for $n$ moles of gas is given by
>   $$PV = nR \frac{T_L-T_o}{ln \big(\frac{T_L}{T_0} \big) }. \tag{2}\label{2}$$
>
> Show that, when $T_L = T_o = T$, the equation of state reduces to the obvious one,
>   $$PV = nRT.\tag{3}\label{3}$$

To prove $\eqref{3}$ from $\eqref{2}$, which is the original question in 5.8, is a simple exercise in calculus. It is not much more difficult to show that if we $\textbf{assume}$ the temperature distribution as in $\eqref{1}$ then $\eqref{2}$ follows and since these maybe homework questions I will skip the derivation.

My question is about the temperature distribution $\eqref{1}$, how realistic is that for a *long* tube. *When* or *how* is it possible to derive from ideal gas properties that it should be linear as in $\eqref{1}$?

Comment: You have an interesting question here. I worry it will be closed though because of how the homework problem is up front and takes up a good chunk of the post. Equations 2 and 3 are completely irrelevant to your question, so why include them here? I suggest that you just give equation 1 as a context and then ask your question.

Comment: I made a rookie mistake forgetting that technically the diffusion equation is $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\alpha\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)$$ so I have momentarily deleted my answer.

Comment: I will say that from what I am finding $\alpha\propto1/\sqrt{T}$

Comment: @BioPhysicist what really has interested me if it is possible to derive the linear temperature dependence from *first principles*, not as the result of a constitutive relationship such as Fourier's law but of something more fundamental, say of a symmetry principle or the 2nd law or whatever for *ideal* gas. But if you insist on bringing in Fourier's Law, then prove that $\alpha$ must be a constant from *first principles*. Is that even possible? Anyhow, thank you for your comments and interest in the question.